# Installing a new fan with old wiring

Tags: wiring, ceiling-fan

I'm trying to install a new fan (which I've done more times than I'd like to admit). This is the first time I've seen such odd wiring. The house is from 1975, and there are three different wiring components coming into the junction box (we'll call them 1, 2 and 3). All three grounds are grouped together. The white from 1 and 2 are tied together with an extra cable being loose. The white from 3 and the black from 1 and 3 are tied together and look burned at the end. the black from 2 is loose. I tied the loose black and white ends to the fan, but it's not working. I'm not sure sure what's going on.[image: black from 1 and 3 tied with white from 3][image: 3 inputs, whites from 1 and 2 tied and loose, ground, and black from 2 hanging down]

Comment: Do you have a 3-wway switch somewhere in the loop? You might need to figure out your incoming hot and neutral, then figure out what pair goes to the switch. Then you can figure out how to wire it up. If power comes into the box BEFORE the switch then you will have a somewhat "odd" wiring setup as you will have white going out to the switch but coming back to the box as black....So you gotta find your mains in first.

Answer (score 1):

Your numbering sounds not quite right.   It sounds like a standard setup, with supply coming into the fan box, supply being carried onward to the next load, and a switch loop for the fan.

Looking at the two whites with the pigtail, these are actually neutral, two whites come from supply and go to onward.  You don't need to care which is which.  The pigtail is neutral for the fan.

In the bundle with two blacks and 1 white, the two blacks go to supply and onward.   The white is being correctly used as always-hot in the switch loop.   White is used to make it easier for electricians to realize this is not a neutral wire; it is always hot and is easily detected.   It should be wrapped in black tape on both ends to designate it a re-tasked hot.

The remaining loose black is switched-hot from the switch loop to the fan.

The fan connects to that loose black (switched-hot) and the white pigtail (neutral).